# Identification of purple haired girl claiming she will pretend to be a cat if things go bad

Tags: koufuku-graffiti

I'm looking for the source of the following image, including which episode of the source it appears in.

Google image search isn't able to find anything.

[image: If it gets too bad, I can just pretend I'm a cat!]

The reason I'm looking for this image, is because I want the image in better quality, given the current one is a small jpg with ugly artifacts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [this scene](https://youtu.be/bqQ1E78wHMM?t=12m20s) from Episode 9 of [**Koufuku Graffiti**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/24629/Koufuku_Graffiti)

> The story follows Ryou, a middle school girl who lives by herself. She has a knack for cooking and makes friendships with everyone through her food. The cooking manga is "full of detailed cuisine art to whet the appetite and slightly erotic meal scenes." The "koufuku" in the title is a wordplay on two Japanese homonyms—one which means "happiness," and another that means "appetite."

The girl is **Kirin Morino**.

[image]